# What is the difference in performance between the C# libraries and the SQL code in a U-SQL query?

Tags: u-sql

I'm struggling with getting a U-SQL script to run in a sane amount of time.

I originally transcribed the script over to U-SQL from an in-house language called SCOPE, but several native functions in SCOPE are missing from U-SQL, so I had to find ways to write them myself.

Early on, I assumed that these features would be faster if I replaced them with SQL, but due to how long the script is taking to run, I'm beginning to question that assumption.

I am currently planning to start doing some experiments on this exact topic, but if anyone already happens to know the answer, I would really appreciate your help. If no one responds, I'll try to answer my own question here to help anyone else who finds themselves having a similar issue.

Comment: someone else did ask about [U-SQL Best practices](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0506326e-debb-42ce-a2d2-3827e21e4a10/usql-best-practices?forum=AzureDataLake), which resulted in a link to [Best Practices and Performance Tuning of U-SQL in Azure Data Lake](https://www.slideshare.net/MichaelRys/best-practices-and-performance-tuning-of-usql-in-azure-data-lake-sql-konferenz-2018), which is a 63-slides long slide show. Hopefully it is of help.

Comment: I've already read through that, it was of some help, but unfortunately there seems to be a lot of context missing without the presentation to go along with it.

Comment: I think answer come close when you provide a script (or piece of it) which has a negative impact on performance. (but please note that it should a reproduceable example)